# Grub missing after upgrade to 12.04 (only blinking underscore on boot)

Tags: 12.04, boot, boot-failure

I recently upgraded to 12.04. After booting, I only got the grub shell with no kernels loaded.

I tried running boot-repair. It told me I use GPT and would need to create a new grub-boot partition. I did this and ran boot-repair again successfully.

However, I now get only a blinking underscore on boot and don't even get a grub shell.

Any ideas? I notice that my new GPT BIOS boot partition isn't the first partition. Can I make it first without having to reformat the first partition that contains all my data?

Boot repair output [**here**](http://paste.debian.net/192571/).

Comment: Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> when you see the BIOS. What do you see?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are correct and the problem is that the BIOS boot partition is set to sda5 and it should be set to you Ubuntu partition where GRUB is installed.

To fix this you can download the [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) live cd/usb and set sda1 as the primary boot device.